# How to save reference to handler in hashmap field

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, mio

I am learning Rust and trying to write a websocket server. The logic is following: WSConnectionFactory creates WSHandler which handle incoming messages and send them to other clients according to arbitrary rules.
The problem is that I don't know how to implement such behavior.

Limitation: I can't change signature of Factory and Handler traits because they are provided by [ws-rs](https://github.com/housleyjk/ws-rs.git) library.

Question: How to implement this using RefCell/Cell?

```
extern crate rand;
extern crate rustc_serialize;
extern crate ws;
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;
#[macro_use]
extern crate env_logger;

use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use rand::random;
use ws::{Factory, Sender, Handler, Handshake, Message, CloseCode, WebSocket};
use ws::Result as WSResult;
use ws::util::Token;

struct WSConnectionFactory<'p> {
    handlers: HashMap<&'p u32, RefCell<&'p WSHandler<'p>>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct WSHandler<'h> {
    uid: &'h u32,
    ws: RefCell<&'h Sender>,
}

impl<'p> Factory for WSConnectionFactory<'p> {
    type Handler = WSHandler<'p>;

    fn connection_made(&mut self, ws: Sender) -> Self::Handler {
        println!("factory.connection_made token={:?}", &ws.token());
        let uid = &random::<u32>();
        let handler = WSHandler {
            uid: uid,
            ws: RefCell::new(&ws),
        };
        self.handlers.insert(uid, RefCell::new(&handler));
        handler
    }
}

impl<'h> Handler for WSHandler<'h> {
    fn on_open(&mut self, _handshake: Handshake) -> WSResult<()> {
        println!("handler.on_open");
        Ok(())
    }
    fn on_message(&mut self, msg: Message) -> WSResult<()> {
        println!("handler.on_message {:?}", msg);
        Ok(())
    }
    fn on_timeout(&mut self, _token: Token) -> WSResult<()> {
        println!("handler.on_timeout {:?}", _token);
        Ok(())
    }
    fn on_close(&mut self, code: CloseCode, reason: &str) {
        println!("handler.on_close code={:?}, reason={:?}", code, reason);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let factory = WSConnectionFactory { handlers: HashMap::new() };
    let ws_socket = WebSocket::new(factory).expect("Can't create WebSocket");
    ws_socket.listen("127.0.0.1:8080").expect("Can't bind to socket");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to return a `WSHandler` from `connection_made` while also storing a reference to the `WSHandler` in the `WSConnectionFactory` struct. This is impossible (with borrowed pointers), because by returning a `WSHandler`, you have no control on what will happen to it (it could be moved or dropped, which would invalidate your pointer). You are also storing borrowed pointers when you should just be storing values directly.

> `WSConnectionFactory` creates `WSHandler` which handle incoming messages and send them to other clients according to arbitrary rules.

If you want to send messages to other clients, you actually need a [`Sender`](http://housleyjk.github.io/ws-rs/ws/struct.Sender.html), not a `WSHandler`. Thankfully, `Sender` implements `Clone`, and from looking quickly through the code, cloning a `Sender` should give you a second "handle" to the same endpoint. Therefore, you should put a `Sender` in your `HashMap`, not a `WSHandler`.

```
extern crate rand;
extern crate rustc_serialize;
extern crate ws;
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;
#[macro_use]
extern crate env_logger;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use rand::random;
use ws::{Factory, Sender, Handler, Handshake, Message, CloseCode, WebSocket};
use ws::Result as WSResult;
use ws::util::Token;

struct WSConnectionFactory {
    handlers: HashMap<u32, Sender>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct WSHandler {
    uid: u32,
    ws: Sender,
}

impl Factory for WSConnectionFactory {
    type Handler = WSHandler;

    fn connection_made(&mut self, ws: Sender) -> Self::Handler {
        println!("factory.connection_made token={:?}", &ws.token());
        let uid = random::<u32>();
        let handler = WSHandler {
            uid: uid,
            ws: ws.clone(),
        };
        self.handlers.insert(uid, ws);
        handler
    }
}

impl Handler for WSHandler {
    fn on_open(&mut self, _handshake: Handshake) -> WSResult<()> {
        println!("handler.on_open");
        Ok(())
    }
    fn on_message(&mut self, msg: Message) -> WSResult<()> {
        println!("handler.on_message {:?}", msg);
        Ok(())
    }
    fn on_timeout(&mut self, _token: Token) -> WSResult<()> {
        println!("handler.on_timeout {:?}", _token);
        Ok(())
    }
    fn on_close(&mut self, code: CloseCode, reason: &str) {
        println!("handler.on_close code={:?}, reason={:?}", code, reason);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let factory = WSConnectionFactory { handlers: HashMap::new() };
    let ws_socket = WebSocket::new(factory).expect("Can't create WebSocket");
    ws_socket.listen("127.0.0.1:8080").expect("Can't bind to socket");
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i missed that Clone is implemented for Sender.